# LightnCandy not found error when updating mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

After updating mediawiki to version 1.35.1, my mainpage now returns this error:

```
MediaWiki internal error.

Original exception: [56b78ecd4218a4dfe16db365] /Main_Page Error from line 67 of /var/www/html/includes/TemplateParser.php: Class 'LightnCandy\LightnCandy' not found
Backtrace:
#0 /var/www/html/skins/Vector/includes/SkinVector.php(71): TemplateParser->__construct()
#1 /var/www/html/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(77): SkinVector->setupTemplate()
#2 /var/www/html/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(271): SkinTemplate->setupTemplateForOutput()
#3 /var/www/html/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(127): SkinTemplate->prepareQuickTemplate()
#4 /var/www/html/includes/skins/SkinTemplate.php(144): SkinTemplate->generateHTML()
#5 /var/www/html/includes/OutputPage.php(2615): SkinTemplate->outputPage()
#6 /var/www/html/includes/MediaWiki.php(947): OutputPage->output()
#7 /var/www/html/includes/MediaWiki.php(960): MediaWiki->{closure}()
#8 /var/www/html/includes/MediaWiki.php(543): MediaWiki->main()
#9 /var/www/html/index.php(53): MediaWiki->run()
#10 /var/www/html/index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#11 {main}
```

Any leads to what I might have missed during the update process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten either `composer update` in your *MediaWiki* directory or `git pull; git checkout REL1_35; composer update` in `skins/Vector`.